# set up a non-BlackBerry email account on BlackBerry device programmatically

Tags: email, blackberry

How can I setup a non-BlackBery email account programmatically on a BlackBerry device?
I have to create an email aggregator which configures all the accounts that can be set up by the BlackBerry device, programmatically. I studied BlackBerry's Mail API, but that can only send mail messages from a default account that is set on the BlackBerry device.

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if there is any way to do this. Mail id delivered to a BlackBerry either from a BES server (under the control of the BES administrator, not the device), or through the BIS service hosted at a RIM Operations Centre. Manipulating the BIS requires authentication of the user to the BIS server. This kind of activity, I believe, falls into the general category of things RIM won't let third party software do on behalf of the user.

Comment: hi i came to know about a third party email client "LogicMail" , this application configured and added a non blackberry email account.... i tried a lot to understand, but not found any way to solve my problem.

 

can u help me some more with "LogicMail"

Comment: If you want assistantace with LogicMail I suggest you contact the developer. I don't see the need for a mail aggregator though, the Blackberry mail client does that already.